# offsetting iterator

Tags: python

I've got this :

```
d = {"date": tuple(date),"open":tuple(open),"close":tuple(close)}

comp1 = zip(d['open'],d['close'])

for i in comp1:   
    if i[0]<i[1]:
        print "bar up"

    if i[0]>i[1]:
        print "bar down"
```

It's all well and good, it tells me if a bar is up or down, now I would like to "shift" my iteration (by one for example), but I don't know the syntax to it . The logic would be :

"if PREVIOUS bar is UP THEN print "yes" if CURRENT bar is also UP " .

Does it make sense ?

cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could turn the iteration you currently do into list comprehension, and then iterate on the list obtained:

```
bars = [i[0]<i[1] for i in comp1]

for b in range(1,len(bars)):
    if bars[b] and bars[b-1]:
        print "yes"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a zip iterator why not just take it to the next level?

```
comp1 = zip(d['open'],d['close'],d['open'][1:],d['close'][1:])
```

and there you have it as long as the tuples have length greater than 1.  Now you can iterate over not only the tuples but also the next element of each tuple too.

Comment: +1; everything else is complicating the issue and/or not understanding what the OP really needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
up = lambda a, b: a < b
for prev, b in zip(comp1, comp1[1:]):
    if up(*prev) and up(*b):
       print "yes"
```

#### Explanation

- `up = lambda a, b: a < b` creates function of two arguments. It is equivalent to [`operator.lt`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.lt).
- `for prev, b in zip(comp1, comp1[1:]):` uses sequence unpacking (the same as in: [`x, y = "xy"`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)), [zip()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function, list [slicing](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#slicings).
- `if up(*prev) and up(*b):` uses the `*expression` syntax for [function calls](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls).

Comment: +1 for the clever use of python.  However, it may be worth a short explanation of what you are doing for those less experienced in it (eg, people looking for this type of answer).

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to have a simple bit of logic to your loop, that implements what you need.  See the following for just a rough idea

```
PreviousWasUp = False
for i in comp1:
    ...
    if i[0] > i[1]:
        if PreviousWasUp:
           print "bar up"
        PreviousWasUp = True
    else:
        PreviousWasUp = False
```

Comment: Even simpler: remember the previous value unconditionally; check where needed. Initially set `previous_value` to `None`.